# Strange behaviour of images inside nested Flexboxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having trouble building a gallery display page.

I've reproduced my issue here

```css
.containerOuter {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:70vh;
}
.containerInner {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  padding:30px;
  min-height:0;
}
ul {
  display:flex;
  min-height:0;
}
img {
  height:100%;
  width:auto;
}
.footnote {
  padding:30px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css">
<div class="containerOuter">
  <div class="containerInner">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500/09f/fff"/></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600/51f/fff"/></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400/56f/fff"/></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700/512/fff"/></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="footnote">Footnote at the bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Essentially, I have a flexbox *containerOuter* (column) with another flexbox *containerInner*  (column) inside it. And inside this, a third flexbox (row). The third flexbox is a horizontal list of *LIs* containing images.

My requirement is to set the height of the *containerOuter* according to the viewport height (e.g. 60vh) and have the *innerContainer* and *LIs* adjust their height to fill this container's height - with the images adjusting their height accordingly, without distortion.

This sounds like it should be not too much trouble right? But I'm really struggling to get it to work.

As you can see from the CodePen, the images, seem to sometimes shrink but the containing *LIs* retain the width of the full size images they contain. And sometimes when you refresh the page, you get a completely different layout. Also - Safari wants to stretch the width of the images to fill the containing *LI*.

Please help :) Thanks very much.

Comment: The Codepen has a different rendering in Chrome and Firefox. Correct in FF?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your aim correctly, you just needed to remove most of the CSS you had, and set the height of each container to 100% (100% of its parent) including the img tags. Elements only respond to 100% height if their parent has a set height:

```css
.containerOuter {
  height:70vh;
}
.containerInner, ul, li, img {
  height: 100%;
}
.containerInner {
  padding:30px;
}
ul {
  display:flex;
}

.footnote {
  padding:30px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css">
<div class="containerOuter">
  <div class="containerInner">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500/09f/fff"/></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600/51f/fff"/></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400/56f/fff"/></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700/512/fff"/></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="footnote">Footnote at the bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've tried this but if I add `display:flex; flex-direction:column` to the containers, the images become distorted. This is required of the design.
Any ideas?

Comment: @BenJackson do the containers only have a single item in them like in the markup? Can you alter the HTML at all, or override them to `display: block`?

Comment: This code is inside a larger page context so it will mess up the rest of my DOM if start messing with the markup. I might be wrong but, I feel like this should be possible without having to do that.

[I've made a page on the live site that illustrates the issue.](https://www.nickiwells.com/image-issue/#pictures)

I want the pictures to line up neatly next to each other and run off the right hand of the page (I'm going to add some gallery navigation functionality with javascript later).

Comment: If you check the link above in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, they all render the page quite differently. Safari is as I intended, Chrome is close and Firefox is a long way off. But I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @BenJackson I don't think I can help any further, sorry. If I were you I would rework the page/site to make the HTML and CSS as simple as possible. Otherwise you're just perpetually trying to play catch up to make everything look nice. Simplicity is key when designing sites.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.containerOuter {
  height:60vh;
}
.containerInner{
  display: flex;
}
.containerInner, li, img {
  height: 100%;
}
.containerInner li{
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.containerInner{
  padding:30px;
}
.footnote {
  padding:30px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css">
<div class="containerOuter">
    <ul class="containerInner">
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500/09f/fff"/></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600/51f/fff"/></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400/56f/fff"/></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700/512/fff"/></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="footnote">Footnote at the bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to acheive this without changing the structure of the DOM. Also - the .containerOuter needs to be a column flex-box.